# java.class.path doesn't bring Manifest.mf Class-Path property

Tags: java, classpath, manifest.mf

I'm trying to get my application classpath.

I have a **jar** (named application.jar) and it have in its **Manifest.mf** other jar files, like `Class-Path: a.jar b.jar`.

Why when I use `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` my jars **a.jar** and **b.jar** are not listed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It possibly has to do with the fact that the `java.class.path` is a system property that is set from the classpath environment variable (`$CLASSPATH` or `-classpath`). These are ignored with the `-jar` option is used.

As per the `java -jar` documentation, when that jar option is used to run an application, only the manifest `Class-Path` is considered and other settings are ignored.
From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html:

> -jar
>
> Execute a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The first argument is the name of a JAR file instead of a startup class name. In order for this option to work, the manifest of the JAR file must contain a line of the form Main-Class: classname. Here, classname identifies the class having the public static void main(String[] args) method that serves as your application's starting point. See the Jar tool reference page and the Jar trail of the Java Tutorial for information about working with Jar files and Jar-file manifests.
>
> **When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.**

Comment: You forgot to mention the most important point: Even though JARs are not listed, the classes inside them are still accessible

Answer (score 0):

That's excactly the question I came along as well. Even if when using `java -cp ..;myTest.jar test2.Needer` I get only "..;myTest.jar" as a result for `java.class.path` property.

*Note*: Even when using the `-cp` parameter the given class-path in the `MANIFEST.MF` is searched! (Couldn't find this information on google and tested myself)

So i don't think that is has something to do with the `-jar` parameter. In [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath?lq=1) you can find

> Expansion of wildcards is done early, prior to the invocation of a program's main method, rather than late, during the class-loading process itself.

Interestingly i found out during my tests: *The classpath in MANFIFEST.MF is searched recursivly.* So if there is an given `test.jar` File in the classpath in MANIFEST.MF of myTest.jar, the class-path in the MANIFEST.MF of the test.jar will be looked up as well (when using `java -cp "myTest.jar" test2.Needer`).

As a result, when the `java.class.path` property would support showing the the classpath of the MANIFEST.MF, it should also show the classpathes of all subsequently depending .jar files. Since the classpath is only searched until classes are found, this wouldn t refer nicely to the lazy loading mechanism.

**TL;DR**: I think that this has nothing to do with the `-jar` Parameter (`-cp` is concerned as well). In my explanation, the support for showing the classpath from the MANIFEST.MF would only come with additional, senseless recursive search costs (because there needn't to be an actual dependency, respectivly what is used from the .jar). And since this sensless search would delay the program start (since the recursive search could be really deep), it is not implemented.