# Spring Boot Properties Outside FAT JAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, config, executable-jar

I'm working on a project and have a use case where I need to provide **application.properties** file for Spring Boot from outside the **JAR**.

According to [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar), the priority order for picking up the application.properties is

1. A /config subdirectory of the current directory
2. The current directory
3. A classpath /config package
4. The classpath root

The issue with first two is I'll need to navigate to the directory containg the configs to run the JAR. It sounds no issue when working on local but wont be a feasible solution when deploying on remote hosts as through CI/CD frameworks.

I'm trying to find a mechanism using classpaths and avoid using spring boot's command line options mentioned over [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features) or setting up environment variables.

I'm unable to figure out how to setup classpath while running FAT JAR and specify configs all together. If you can, please help me figure it out!

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT** : I understand there are ways to achieve this using Spring Boot's command line options such as spring.config or loader.path etc.

I was trying to find a more implicit solution based on classpath and directory structures only to make it less coupled with the fact that Spring Boot is being used.

Comment: Have you tried to use `java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=another-location.properties`

Comment: Hey 
I wish to use classpaths directly without having to use Spring Boot run time options provided such as spring.config, loader.config etc
Just JAR, properties file and classpath specfifying the required locations to JAR and configs. (Last 2 of the priority options)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties), you can define external config locations using the `spring.config.location` property. More specifically:

> If `spring.config.location` contains directories (as opposed to files),
>   they should end in / (and, at runtime, be appended with the names
>   generated from `spring.config.name` before being loaded, including
>   profile-specific file names). 
>   Files specified in
>   `spring.config.location` are used as-is, with no support for
>   profile-specific variants, and are overridden by any profile-specific
>   properties.
>
> Config locations are searched in reverse order. By default, the
>   configured locations are:
>
> `classpath:/,classpath:/config/,file:./,file:./config/.`
>
> The resulting
>   search order is the following:
>
> `file:./config/ file:./ classpath:/config/ classpath:/`
>
> When custom
>   config locations are configured by using `spring.config.location`, they
>   replace the default locations. For example, if `spring.config.location`
>   is configured with the value
>
> `classpath:/custom-config/,file:./custom-config/`
>   the search order
>   becomes the following:
>
> `file:./custom-config/ classpath:custom-config/`
>
> Alternatively, when
>   custom config locations are configured by using
>   `spring.config.additional-location`, they are used in addition to the
>   default locations. 
>   Additional locations are searched before the
>   default locations. For example, if additional locations of
>   `classpath:/custom-config/,file:./custom-config/` 
>   are configured, the
>   search order becomes the following:
>
> `file:./custom-config/ classpath:custom-config/ file:./config/ file:./ classpath:/config/ classpath:/`

An example usage for a directory containing your external configi would look like:

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=file:/custom-config-dir/
```

Or directly to an external config file:

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=file:/custom-config-dir/custom-config.properties
```

Comment: Hey
I appreciate the answer but we're trying to achieve it without using spring provided run time options. I have added an EDIT to question. Do you know a way coherent with that?

Answer (score 0):

Specify custom config location as VM argument is another option.

```
java -Dspring.config.location=<config-dir-path> -jar demo.jar
```

Comment: More options on this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716796/spring-boot-executable-jar-with-classpath

Comment: Thanks for the answer but we're trying to achieve it without using spring provided run time options. I have added an EDIT to question. Do you know a way coherent with that?

Comment: what do you meant by spring provided runtime options . Do you mean like uing it through a rest service kind of stuff . You Want to Change the Properties in Runtime while your app is running ?

Comment: i mean spring boot run time options to set spring.config , loader.path etc
I want to use classpath and jar only